# How to find the location of two nodes of the same name nested in two different tags?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<employees>
   <employee>   <!--forgot to include an attribute-->
      <name>John</name>
      <jobs>
          <job>Writer</job>
          <job>Artist</job>
     </jobs>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <name>John</name>
      <jobs>
          <job>Engineer</job>
          <job>Editor</job>
     </jobs>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

If I want to get the jobs of people with name="John" XPath returns all four jobs belonging to one "John".  I want 2+2 different jobs done by two different "John"s each.

I use the XPath expression

```
"//employees/employee[name='John']/jobs/job/text()"
```

Is there a way in XPath in java using count or some other function to do this??

Comment: @@Niranjani S: Could you please, edit your question and specify what is the exact result you want to get -- list the exact XML nodes you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath is always going to return a flat list, no matter where the nodes are found, which is why you simply get 4 pieces of text.  If you want to group them by their parent nodes, you need to first search for the Johns and with those results, do a nested loop - for each John, do an XPath for the jobs, starting at that node.  How you wish to group them in Java is up to you - perhaps a Map of String (name) to List of String (job).

Comment: Getting the employee nodes with name as "John" and then traversing the employee nodes using getChildNodes() did the work!

Answer (score 2):

**XPath is (only) a query language for XML documents** -- the result of evaluation an XPath expression is never a modified node -- XPath alone doesn't change the structure and/or contents of any node.

What you want returned is modified `<employee>` elements with only their `<jobs>` child and this cannot be achieved with XPath alone.

**The closest to what you want is**:

```
/*/employee[name='John']/jobs
```

**This selects the following**:

```
    <jobs>
        <job>Writer</job>
        <job>Artist</job>
    </jobs>
    <jobs>
        <job>Engineer</job>
        <job>Editor</job>
    </jobs>
```

**What I guess is the result wanted by you can be produced absolutely easy with this XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/employee[name='John']/node()[not(self::comment())]"/>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <!--forgot to include an attribute-->
        <name>John</name>
        <jobs>
            <job>Writer</job>
            <job>Artist</job>
        </jobs>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>John</name>
        <jobs>
            <job>Engineer</job>
            <job>Editor</job>
        </jobs>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<name>John</name>
<jobs>
   <job>Writer</job>
   <job>Artist</job>
</jobs>
<name>John</name>
<jobs>
   <job>Engineer</job>
   <job>Editor</job>
</jobs>
```

Comment: @Niranjani S: Don't feel guilty -- just jump on the wagon for a ride. You won't regret it :)